# Need row-wise data presented as column-wise data with intersystems cache sql

Tags: sql, caching, intersystems-cache

I have the query

```
select cdc.pt_ID, cdc.alpha_code     
from c_data_core left outer join
     d_code_table dct
     on dct.facility = cdc.facility and dct.alpha_code = cdc.alpha_code
      where cdc.alpha_code  in ( 'a1','a2','a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6')
```

After it executes it looks like this:

```
cdc.pt_ID           cdc.alpha_code
---------           --------------
57                  a1
11                  a3
20                  a5
49                  a3
62                  a5
57                  a3
11                  a1
20                  a5
49                  a2
62                  a4
```

and I need it to output like this:

```
cdc.patId   cdc.alpha_code_1   cdc.alpha_code_2   cdc.alpha_code_3   cdc.alpha_code_4   cdc.alpha_code_5
---------   ----------------   ----------------   ----------------   ----------------   ----------------
 57             a1                  a2                 a3                  a4                 a5
 11             a3                  a1                 a5                  a2                 a4
 20             a5                  a3                 a2                  a1                 a4
 49             a3                  a1                 a5                  a2                 a4
 62             a5                  a4                 a2                  a3                 a1
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I would really appreciate it!

Cache does not support "pivot".

Comment: (1) Your desired results seems to have more data than the data the query returns.  (2) You seem to be assuming an ordering in the results.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: @Gordon - It does, I wasn't very accurate when I was drafting the question, I was focused more on a method of accomplishing this task. My apologies! I'll definitely be more aware of what I post in the future. Thanks for bringing that to my attention!